# Monocle ebook reader - how to load a book data object rather than sample text

Tags: javascript, pdf, filereader, monocle

I am trying to test monocle for a brief pdf, but I can't even get the super-basic sample to work with the index, content1 and content2 files. All that shows up in the body is the word "test" that's currently in the reader div. Is there some other code that I'm supposed to insert in place of the word test?

@magicianlam got a one-page pdf to work (would you mind posting your index.html so I can see the whole thing)?

I've been at this a few hours and can't find complete get started instructions, and GitHub is getting circular as I click and read and still can't put it all together. Also, the sample book there doesn't work, even if I correct the file paths to what must be a new structure in 3.20.

For reference, I downloaded the latest version (3.20).  Also, I am not able to see the controls tests (no content shows up in the frames) or the Dickens test (no content or controls show up, just the background) in IE, FF or Chrome, so maybe the version itself has an issue.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: It will be hard to say anything not seeing your code

Comment: Thanks for replying. (pt 1 of 2) For anyone stumped by getting Monocle to work, here are lay steps to create the infrastructure: 1) Create a folder for your ebook files.  2) make an html version of your ebook and save it to that folder.  3) create a folder called "scripts" and save monocore.js there (you can copy and paste from the GitHub link to Notepad or another text editor.  The first line of that file should be <!DOCTYPE html>. 4) create a folder called "styles" and save monocore.css there.  You can create that file by copying the GitHub text to your editor, starting with <!DOCTYPE html>.

Comment: (pt 2/2) The ebook governing document. Back to GitHub-https://github.com/joseph/monocle) to section "Integrating Monocle." Copy that code into Notepad, starting with <!DOCTYPE html>, then wrap that code inside of <html></html> tags. In the body, replace "Hello world." with the html of your book content (no header, styles, etc.).  You now can view this file in a browser as an ebook. Use monocore.css to change page size and other elements.  NOTE: if you want to reference the book as an object instead of embedding it in the governing doc, a coder can fix your monocore.js file.  It's very quick.